# Sorting data in R and using a specific study eye

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several continous variable measured in the right and the left eye.

One variable, e.g. elevation of optic nerve, defines the worst eye (= which then makes the study eye). Other variables, e.g. length of the eye bulb, then needs to be correlated with this. After determining the worst eye/the study eye - how do I make sure R always uses this same eye for the subsequent analyses ?

My data looks like this:

[image: 1]

Eg.: ID17 sin_ons is larger than dxt_ons = sin_ons is the study eye. Now R needs to only use the variable sin_etd, sin_eld, sin_after ? Whereas ID45 is opposite - R needs to use only dxt-variables.

This is probably basic, but I'm not an R expert by any means. Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) on reasons to avoid using images when sharing sample data.

Below is one approach to your example using `tidyverse`.

First, put your data into long format. Then you could use `separate` so you could have 2 columns, one for your variable name, and one to indicate eye (dexter or sinister). For example, "sin_onsd" becomes "sin" and "onsd" in separate columns.

Then, you can `group_by` your `record_id`. For each `record_id`, compare the "sin" and "dex" values for `onsd` to determine the worse eye. An `ifelse` will compare the values and indicate the result in a new column `worse_eye`.

Finally, you can `filter` your data to only include measures where the `worse_eye` is the same as the `eye` present for a given measure.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -record_id) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("eye", "var"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(worse_eye = ifelse(value[var == "onsd" & eye == "dxt"] > 
                            value[var == "onsd" & eye == "sin"],
                            "dxt", "sin")) %>%
  filter(eye == worse_eye)
```

**Output**

```
  record_id eye   var        value worse_eye
      <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    
1        17 sin   onsd         5.2 sin      
2        17 sin   etd         21   sin      
3        17 sin   eld         19.2 sin      
4        17 sin   onsd_after   4.2 sin      
5        45 dxt   onsd         5.6 dxt      
6        45 dxt   etd         21   dxt      
7        45 dxt   eld         18.6 dxt      
8        45 dxt   onsd_after   5.5 dxt
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(record_id = c(17, 45), dxt_onsd = c(4.9, 5.6), 
    sin_onsd = c(5.2, 5.5), dxt_etd = c(19.9, 21), sin_etd = c(21, 
    19.1), dxt_eld = c(18.9, 18.6), sin_eld = c(19.2, 16.3), 
    dxt_onsd_after = c(4.8, 5.5), sin_onsd_after = c(4.2, 5.7
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```